# dynamic external javascript generated using php

Tags: customization, javascript, variables

How to write an external javascript file with dynamic variable values generated using php from wp db values?

So instead of using wp_localize_script for inline js variables,  I'd like to use wp_enqueue_script with $src pointing to this php file acting like external js.

So far, on the external js using php, the content as follow:

```
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
$params = array(
  'timezone_string'           => get_option( 'timezone_string' ),
  'jump_to_top'           => __( 'Jump to top' ),
  .....
);
echo "$timezone_string $jump_to_top;
.....
```

When viewing page source, the external script file is listed correctly, but clicking on the external file link, it takes me to home page. I added wp-load.php, still the same.

How to do this correctly?

Comment: How are you including this js?

Comment: using wp_enqueue_script, the written format will appear as just as this:  <script type='text/javascript' src='http:/domain.com/js/js.php'></script>

Comment: Why you don't want to use `wp_localize_script`?

Comment: I need external js, not inline. Wp_localize_script is for inline

Comment: [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) is for external, enqueued js, not inline.

Comment: Milo, wp_localize_script only generate inline script, not external js script.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than generating whole script dynamically it would make more sense (from logical and caching perspective) to use static script that will fetch data required via generic [Ajax request](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) to WP.